# Embed Image in Email Message in MPDF Using PHP

Tags: php, html, mpdf

Is there a way to embed an image in a message body in MPDF using php? Simply adding the HTML image tag as shown in the snippet below causes the actual tag to display in an e-mail.

```
$message = '<img src="Signature%20Card.jpg"/>';
```

Thank you for any ideas.

By the way, I am also sending an attached PDF. That part works fine though; only embedding the image does not work.

Below is the code for actually sending the e-mail:

```
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
$is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
```

Comment: First, mPDF is very touchy about proper HTML. Try adding the closing slash to the img tag: `$message = '<img src="Signature%20Card.jpg" />';` Second, can you clarify a bit - are you generating a PDF and then attaching it to an email? Can you maybe post some more code related to including this tag?

Comment: Closing the image tag with a slash does not fix the problem.

Comment: Also, I am sending an attached PDF, but that part works fine.

Comment: What method are you using to send the email? Can you post that part of your code?

Comment: how about the full file file path

Comment: Using the full file path does not work either.

Comment: dont include the code for sending, when its noting to do with the problem.

Comment: ^I included the sending code because another individual in the comments requested it.

Comment: well your topic is misleading when you say its nothing to do with actully sending the email

Comment: Looks like the $message is going into the header, rather than the message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `$message` variable into the body of the email for this to work properly. Currently the code is going into the header rather than the email message body. Change these lines by removing the middle line:

```
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
//$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
```

And in the final line of code, place the `$message` variable into the mail command:

```
$is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```